# How to run a script if a user SSHs into an non-existent user?

Tags: python, ssh

I have a Python script that creates a new user and configures it, I want this to be ran anytime a user SSHs into the server but the username isn't a valid one, how could I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is an incredibly bad idea. How would they learn what password you assigned? Consider how easy it would be to write a denial of service attack to log in as millions of unknown users. Hackers do that EVERY DAY to any public-facing server. Much better idea to have a web site where people register for a new username.

Comment: I don't really care about the security I am doing it to run some tests.

Comment: ssh issues a log message to `/var/log/auth.log` when a connection is closed due to invalid user.  You can monitor that file for those failures.